# how can the Controller detect changes to child entities/rows in a View?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

What's the most appropriate approach to the following scenario?

I have two models:

1. TimeSheet: Consisting of four properties: `DayStartTime`, `DayEndTime`, `BreakTime`, `List<TimeSheetHours>`
2. TimeSheetHours: Consisting of four properties: `ClientId`, `ProjectId`, `HoursWorked`

My time sheet view is strongly typed to a `IEnumerable<TimeSheet>` list. This list contains 7 TimeSheet models, one for each day of the week Sunday-Saturday. This time sheet view uses an editor tempate to produce input fields for `DayStartTime`, `DayEndTime`, `BreakTime`, for each of the days of week:

Each day contains a section for clients & projects. Clicking an "add" button fires an ajax function which calls a controller action to render a partial view dynamically inserting a row of controls (Client combobox, Project combobox, HoursWorked textbox) into the appropriate clients & projects section for that day:

I'm having a hard time understanding how I can update each timesheet model's `List<TimeSheetHours>` when I add a new client/project row via the ajax call.

So in the end, when I submit to the controller for inserting the timesheet, I have everything thing I need for each timesheet model in the list I produced the view.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: check out my answer, should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to massage the names of these elements before they're posted to look like how I have it below or in your ajax call pass in the index of the `TimeSheet` and then create the name:

`TimeSheetHours` Index = 0

```
<input type="text" id="TimeSheet[0]_TimeSheetHours[0]_DayStartTime" 
    name="TimeSheet[0].TimeSheetHours[0].DayStartTime" value="1" />
<input type="text" id="TimeSheet[0]_TimeSheetHours[0]_DayEndTime" 
    name="TimeSheet[0].TimeSheetHours[0].DayEndTime" value="2" />
<input type="text" id="TimeSheet[0]_TimeSheetHours[0]_BreakTime" 
    name="TimeSheet[0].TimeSheetHours[0].BreakTime" value="1" />
```

`TimeSheetHours` Index = 1

```
<input type="text" id="TimeSheet[0]_TimeSheetHours[1]_DayStartTime" 
    name="TimeSheet[0].TimeSheetHours[1].DayStartTime" value="3" />
<input type="text" id="TimeSheet[0]_TimeSheetHours[1]_DayEndTime" 
    name="TimeSheet[0].TimeSheetHours[1].DayEndTime" value="4" />
<input type="text" id="TimeSheet[0]_TimeSheetHours[1]_BreakTime" 
    name="TimeSheet[0].TimeSheetHours[1].BreakTime" value="0" />
```

You're probably much better off intercepting the `submit` event and iterating over each `TimeSheetHours` html-represented element and assigning the name as a mask and then submitting the form. This should allow the model binder to reconstruct your `List<TimeSheet>` with a populated `List<TimeSheetHours>` property.

---

Here's a good tutorial on how to solve this issue of posting a collection: [ASP.NET MVC 2 Model Binding for a Collection](http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/03/13/asp-net-mvc-2-model-binding-for-a-collection.aspx)

Comment: Hello Hunter. Appreciate your reply. The above three fields are the not the issue actually. It's the TimeSheetHour fields: ClientId, ProjectId, and HoursWorked. These fields are added via the partial page. And I've done some field name overrides to get the names in a similar format as you indicated above.

Comment: This same principle of naming can be applied to those `select` elements

Comment: Hunter, as I read your answer a bit further, I wanted to add that I am actually passing an id which represents the number of the model 0-7 with the ajax call which renders the partial view for the timesheethours fields. I pass that id to the partial view to override the ids of the fields like: 

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClientId, Model.Clients, new { @id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "[" + ViewBag.FieldId + "]"})

Comment: The following is an example of the name that I create: [0.1].ClientId. 0 being the model number(index), I then append the row number .1 as I can have many timesheethours or rows of the same fields: clientid, projectid, hoursworked. 

Hope some of this helps. Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Hunter, thanks for your assistance. Your answers eventually led me into the right direction. I basically had my prefixes incorrect. Once I lined them up properly MVC did it's magic and updated the timesheethours lists accordingly. 

Cheers

Comment: Glad to hear it! MVC is awesome